# In the U.S., are major dental procedures considered tax-deductible?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, healthcare

If someone is going to undergo a major dental/medical procedure ($40k+), is there any way to deduct the money paid for the procedure, or at least part of it?

Comment: Is the procedure in question considered medically advisable or necessary, or is it cosmetic surgery?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea There are multiple points of infection.  I'm not sure if it's "technically" considered medically advisable.  The person is opting for implants over extraction.

Comment: @David IMHO implants are considered "advisable". Verify with your doctor. I had one covered in full by insurance (which means that it would be tax deductible without the insurance).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If medical, not cosmetic, you can deduct medical expenses to the extent they [exceed 7.5% of your adjusted gross income](http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc502.html).

Note: it's been announced that starting in 2013 the deduction is for amounts exceeding 10% of AGI.

Answer (score 3):

Does your company offer a [Medical Savings Account](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_savings_account%20%22medical%20Savings%20account)? That can allow you to reduce your taxable income. You normally have to join during "open season".

Another option is [Medical and Dental Expenses](http://www.irs.gov/newsroom/article/0,,id=235318,00.html) above 7.5% of your adjusted gross income. This is a high hurdle to meet, and only reduces your taxes by the tax rate x the amount your bills exceed 7.5%

Comment: Unfortunately the open season is closed, and 40k+ is a bit too much to add to the MSA.  Plus, the MSA/HSA max is ~3k, which is far less than the $40k+ that will be paid.